# Obtain the commom coefficient of a quadratic sum in sympy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, symbolic-math

I have an equation of the type:
`z = a*x**2 + b*y**2 + a*y**2` and I would like to find the commum coefficient (`a` in the example) of `(x**2 + y**2)`.
I tried the following:

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq
x,y,z,a,b = symbols('x,y,z,a,b')

eq = Eq(z, a*x**2 + b*y**2 + a*y**2)
coef = eq.rhs.coeff(x**2 + y**2)
display(coef)
```

but the result is 0. It works well for a unique quadratic term, but could I get the coefficient `a` for the sum `x**2 + y**2` with this or any functionality of sympy?

Comment: Please turn that code in a minimal working example. What are `b`, `Eq`, `display`?

Comment: and your code return `0` not "null"

Comment: Sorry @cards, I edited with the correction. b is another coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use `collect` wrt the free-symbol `a` (either as a string or Symbol object).

```
eq = Eq(z, a*x**2 + b*y**2 + a*y**2)
print(eq.rhs.collect('a'))
```

---

Edit

The problem could be quite complex because it depends on the nesting level of the operations in the expression [the whole chain of operations build a tree structure].

Here, a very very basic example that work for easy-expression, assumed `a` to be known in advance as a kind of reference parameter.

```
terms = eq.rhs.args

for term in terms:
    if a in term.free_symbols:
        print(term/a)
```

Comment: In this case, my output is the complete equation instead the coefficient `a`.

Comment: My answer is based on the title

Comment: I changed the title to make it more clear that the goal is to get `a`. I have an equation that is way more complex, then the idea would be to get terms that multiply `(x**2 + y**2)`.

Comment: Yes, I am on it. Thanks for the edits